# Different height and width property for PDF File in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

For a certain PDF file if I use `page.getMediaBox().getWidth()` and `page.getMediaBox().getHeight()` to get width and height of PDF file page using PDFBox, if shows values which are different than the values I am getting using the `PDFBoxDebugger`. What might be the reason? I am attaching the screenshot for the `PDFDebugger`. I am using PDFBox-2.0.9 version. The values I am getting from `page.getMediaBox().getWidth()` and `page.getMediaBox().getHeight()` are 531.36597 and 647.99603 respectively which do not match with the `PDFBoxDebugger` values. (And it only occurs for the first page of PDF, for further pages it works fine)

[image: MediaBox shows different values than the values using the MediaBox() method]

Comment: Please edit your question to show what values you are getting, and please mention the version. The width here would be 531.366, the height 648.296. (Btw in most cases the cropBox is the thing you want)

Comment: As implied in @Tilman's comment: The **MediaBox** page entry contains the coordinates of two opposite corners of the box, not the coordinates of one corner plus width and height. Thus, the `page.getMediaBox().getWidth()` and `page.getMediaBox().getHeight()` values do not necessarily need to be among the **MediaBox** page entry values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tilman already stated in a comment, the values to expect are

- a width of 1282.2 - 750.834 = **531.366** and
- a height of 849.593 - 201.597 = **647.996** (corrected value).

The observed values

> 531.36597 and 647.99603

correspond to the expected values well enough considering the accuracy of the `float` type.

---

I assume the op misunderstands the values of the **MediaBox** array. They do not contain the width or height as explicit values but *the coordinates of two opposite corners of the box*.

The **MediaBox** value is specified to have the type *rectangle*, cf. ISO 32000-1 table 30 *Entries in a page object*. And a *rectangle* is specified as

> a specific array object used to describe locations oon a page and bounding boxes for a variety of objects and written as an array of four numbers giving the coordinates of a pair of diagonally opposite corners,

cf. ISO 32000-1 section 4.40 **rectangle**.

---

As also already mentioned by Tilman you probably should be looking at the **CropBox** instead.